# Optimizar consulta con relaciones

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una consulta (metodo index) que devuelve todos los registros, el tema es las relaciones como esta hecho, el cual estoy tratando de optimizar, las relaciones de la consulta son:

```
 private function campaignRelations($companyId = 0, $establishmentId = 0, $advisorId = 0) {
    return [
        'companies' => function ($query) use ($companyId) {
            if($companyId) {
                $query->where('id',$companyId);
            }
        },
        'companies.warehouses',
        'companies.warehouses.companies',
        'companies.warehouses.products',
        'companies.warehouses.products.cropsAdvisor.crop',
        'companies.warehouses.products.laborsAdvisor.labor',
        'companies.warehouses.products.warehouses' => function ($query) use ($advisorId) {
            $query->where('advisor_id', $advisorId);
        },
        'companies.warehouses.products.supply.subtype',
        'companies.warehouses.products.supply.type',
        'companies.warehouses.products.supply',
        'companies.warehouses.products.unit',
        'lots' => function ($query) use ($companyId, $establishmentId) {
            if($companyId) {
                $query->where('company_id', $companyId);
            }
            if ($establishmentId) {
                $query->where('establishment_id', $establishmentId);
            }
        },
        'lots.cropsAdvisor',
        'lots.cropsAdvisor.crop.stages',
        'lots.cropsAdvisor.crop.cropAdvisors',
        'lots.establishment',
    ];
}
```

y esta consulta me devuelve muchos registros repetidos donde solo varia la tabla pivot en muchos casos:

```
   {
                "id": 6,
                "advisor_id": 1,
                "country_id": 1,
                "tax_identifier": "27337564657",
                "logo_original_path": null,
                "logo_path": null,
                "name": "Azul Hermanos",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2019-06-07 12:40:30",
                "updated_at": "2019-06-07 12:40:30",
                "pivot": {
                    "campaign_id": 1,
                    "company_id": 6,
                    "lot_id": 6,
                    "id": 6
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "advisor_id": 1,
                "country_id": 1,
                "tax_identifier": "27337564657",
                "logo_original_path": null,
                "logo_path": null,
                "name": "Azul Hermanos",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2019-06-07 12:40:30",
                "updated_at": "2019-06-07 12:40:30",
                "pivot": {
                    "campaign_id": 1,
                    "company_id": 6,
                    "lot_id": 13,
                    "id": 13
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "advisor_id": 1,
                "country_id": 1,
                "tax_identifier": "27337564657",
                "logo_original_path": null,
                "logo_path": null,
                "name": "Azul Hermanos",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2019-06-07 12:40:30",
                "updated_at": "2019-06-07 12:40:30",
                "pivot": {
                    "campaign_id": 1,
                    "company_id": 6,
                    "lot_id": 20,
                    "id": 20
                }
            },
```

no estoy encontrando una forma de optimizar esto, si es que se puede

Comment: Uff, realmente está muy grande ese eager loading, un dato muy pequeño, es que cuando traes la relación más lejana que buscas, no necesitas traer las más cercanas. Ejemplo: Si ya tienes `'companies.warehouses.products.cropsAdvisor.crop',`, no necesitas traer ni `'companies.warehouses',` ni `'companies.warehouses.products',`. En cuanto a verificar esos registros aparentemente duplicados, tendrías que depurar cada relación que estás cargando, una a una, y revisar en dónde se genera dicho resultado.

Comment: y como hago para no traer 'companies.warehouses' por ejemplo ?

Comment: Borrando esa línea...